# How to tell FaceBook to not use any image when sharing a page?

Tags: facebook

When the og:image tag is not defined facebook searches for other images available on the page. I need to tell facebook no to use any images if the og:image tag is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't a feature, Facebook's crawler will always try to find the best image if you don't specify one

Comment: Sadly, this is the correct answer. I think that there could be a work around for this, not worth the trouble though. I wonder if the scrapper can pick up images that are added after initial page rendering and point to a data url...